# Eight (wisdom) teeth extraction in Germany

Tags: cavity, gingivitis, tooth-extraction, wisdom-teeth

My eight tooth (on the bottom :) ) has made its way through gingiva, and it has grown in the direction of 7th tooth. That makes difficult to clean food remains from the place of contact of 7th and 8th.

Till now there is only one trouble - cleaning teeth, but my doctor said that we should plan to extract 8th tooth so to eleminate further problems (t.g. caries because of difficulties in cleaning)

I've read that there is a practice of planned extraction of 8th teeth in Germany. Is it so? At what age? Any other important details?

Comment: Extraction of wisdom teeth is a fairly routine practice in all developed nations. You might not want to limit your question just to Germany.